# locale timestamp causing overflow when executing python script

Tags: python, environment-variables, raspberry-pi, timestamps

I'm trying to run a python script I wrote on my Raspberry Pi Zero, but I keep getting the error `OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t`.
I'm relatively certain it's something with the 32-bit ARM architecture of the pi, but I can't seem to figure out a workaround.

Here's the traceback (mostly for posterity as I don't think python is the issue):

```
  File "twitter.py", line 37, in <module>
    t.run.Search(c)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/run.py", line 288, in Search
    run(config, callback)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/run.py", line 209, in run
    get_event_loop().run_until_complete(Twint(config).main(callback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/run.py", line 150, in main
    await task
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/run.py", line 194, in run
    await self.tweets()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/run.py", line 141, in tweets
    await output.Tweets(tweet, self.config, self.conn)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/output.py", line 142, in Tweets
    await checkData(tweets, config, conn)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/output.py", line 116, in checkData
    panda.update(tweet, config)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twint/storage/panda.py", line 67, in update
    day = weekdays[strftime("%A", localtime(Tweet.datetime))]
OverflowError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

I've done some searching and found similar(ish) issues, but most of them are with directly converting timestamps, where mine appears to be with setting a time. I've tried rebooting the Pi and immediately running the script to see if the issue is with the Pi's uptime, but that returned the same.

My conclusion from all of the above is that it might be something with the pi's ntp time sync?

Heres my `timedatectl status` output:

```
               Local time: Wed 2020-01-22 17:39:22 EST
           Universal time: Wed 2020-01-22 22:39:22 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: America/New_York (EST, -0500)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

The timezone and such is correct, so honestly I'm drawing a blank here.
Anyone have any tips?

Comment: Hi, did you end up solving this issue? I have a similar problem.

Comment: this is issue has to do Raspbian's C localtime() or gmtime() limitation 

In Python's [datetime.fromtimestamp official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) it is mentioned that:


```fromtimestamp() may raise OverflowError, if the timestamp is out of the range of values supported by the platform C localtime() or gmtime() functions, and OSError on localtime() or gmtime() failure. It’s common for this to be restricted to years in 1970 through 2038. ```

Comment: Any development on the issue? 
I also wrote kinda of the same in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481616/python-overflowerror-creating-date-from-timestamp-in-32bit-system